# Why 'web3.eth.syncing' (Truffle console) returns 'false' when actually the testnet is running?

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, ethereumjs, fast-sync

I run the ethereum testnet using the following command

```
geth --testnet --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024  --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303"
```

But truffle console returns 'false' for 'web3.eth.syncing'

```
user@user:~/voting$ truffle console
truffle(development)> web3.eth.syncing
false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, when the network is fully synced, this function returns false. If you delete the chain and start redownloading it, I'd expect the function to return true.

Comment: Thanks. can you please tell me the average time taken to completely download the test-net blockchain and the size of the chain data.